# Use the properties of linear combinations to derive means and standard deviations

Tags: distributions

I'm studying different sampling distributions, and have run into a difficult problem with linear combinations. How may I use the properties of linear combinations of random variables to derive the means and standard deviations of the sample distributions for the difference in two sample proportions and for the difference in two sample means?

Answer (score 3):

There are three basic properties* that are very useful; you will use them over and over

1) Linearity of expectation: $$E(aX+bY+c)=aE(X)+bE(Y)+c$$

2) Variance of a linear combination, uncorrelated: $$\text{Var}(aX+bY+c)=a^2\,\text{Var}(X)+b^2\,\text{Var}(Y)$$

3) Variance of a linear combination, general: $$\text{Var}(aX+bY+c)=a^2\,\text{Var}(X)+b^2\,\text{Var}(Y)+2ab\,\text{Cov}(X,Y)$$

Independence implies 0 correlation, so the second one comes up a lot.

You get standard deviations by calculating variances and then taking square roots at the end.

* (well, two, since one is a special case of another, but that special case crops up so often it's worth listing as one of its own)

Comment: I would also throw in a constant $c$ in there.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Okay. There's nothing lost by doing so, and it may help someone.