# Variance of Uncorrelated Variables

Tags: variance, random-variable

I know the typical variance formula for correlated random variables, but can't seem to find the variance for a linear combination of uncorrelated random variables.

Now there are a few things regarding uncorrelated variables that obviously play into this:
- Two random variables are said to be uncorrelated if their Cov(X,Y)=0
- The variance of the *sum* of uncorrelated random variables is the sum of their variances

But what about the variance itself for a linear combination of these r.v.'s?

Comment: What is the question? You seem to know everything already

Comment: Is there a formula for the variance of a linear combination of uncorrelated random variables? I know the rules regarding variances, but can't seem to find the formula for a linear combination of these r.v.'s anywhere. Sorry, I edited my question to include "linear combination"

Comment: It is the sum of the individual variances

Comment: for two variables, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/123963/805 or more generally https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties (then taking advantage of the fact that when the covariances are 0 the terms including them will drop out)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use the properties of linear combinations to derive means and standard deviations](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123914/use-the-properties-of-linear-combinations-to-derive-means-and-standard-deviation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $Z$ be a linear combination of two random uncorrelated variables $X$ and $Y$ so that:

$$Z=aX+bY$$

Then:

$$var(Z)=a^2·var(X)+b^2·var(Y)$$

Answer (score 5):

There's some confusion. "Variance" is not a property of a pair of variables, it's a property of a random variable. If your r.v. happens to be the sum of two others, then there is a formula for that variance as a function of the other two. It depends on the correlation, and if that correlation is zero, then plug in zero, and there you go. To take from Pere's answer, if 
$$
Z = aX+bY
$$
then
$$\newcommand{\var}{{\rm var}}
\var(Z)=a^2·\var(X)+b^2·\var(Y) + 2·{\rm cov}(X, Y)
$$

Comment: Isn't a factor $a.b$ needed before the covariance term?

Comment: @f.g., you shouldn't edit someone's post to correct it. Instead, leave a comment, downvote, post your own answer, etc.

Comment: That was my own answer. "Filipe" was just the profile I was using on another machine. (for boring reasons).

Answer (score 5):

If $X_1, ..., X_K$ are all uncorrelated with each other, then

$$ {\rm var} \left( \sum_{i=1}^K a_i X_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{K} a_i^2 {\rm var}(X_i) $$

Comment: This was already said in the two previous answers...

Comment: The previous two answers pre-specified the case where $K=2$

Comment: Yes, but extending it to K>2 cases is pretty obvious since it follows from the same general properties of variance...

Comment: Tim, all of the answers here are pretty obvious. This is a question with an obvious answer that takes about 3 seconds to google. And it's a duplicate. And the OP gives the answer in the statement of this question. I don't know why you're singling me out here. The question was already bumped by gung so I went ahead and added this answer because the OP asked about the variance of a linear combination, without pre-specifying that there are only two. I added something beyond what was already said (unlike the previous two answers, frankly). ~Fin~

Comment: If it is a duplicate and already has answers (given a year ago, with accepted answer among them), then I really can't see any reason to provide another answer to it...

Comment: If I'd searched and found a question that had been inactive for 6 months and bumped it just to add this answer, I guess I could understand your point of view, but I didn't. The fact is, it popped up at the top of the queue, I read it, and I added a piece of information that no one else had mentioned yet. Was it a profound piece of information? No. But, it could be useful to a future reader. Whether or not the OP accepted an answer seems immaterial.

Comment: Ok. But then, if you find it important to discuss the K>2 case, maybe you could add some details, e.g. how K=2 case extends to K>2, prove why does it still hold etc.? In such case I'd be inclined to agree with you and even up-vote your answer.

Comment: I gave the general answer. The others key in on the special case where $K=2$.  I think, in light of my answer, the others are useless. Not the other way around. I guess you could go from the $K=2$ to the $K>2$ case by using the $K=2$ answer iteratively, but that doesn't sound like a useful exercise. You're welcome to add that but I'm not going to. I find it useful to think of the general case as delivering the answer for the $K=2$ case, not the other way around. It's OK if we don't agree. Do whatever you need to do in terms of voting (or not voting).